# Sorry, I'm new. to this SE

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking

spoil the unlukcy number for this text

fbeel, V'z arj fb gvuf jvyy or fchre rm.

3 > 4 and
4 > 3

`^\w|[A-Z]|[^w](?=i)` is the whole clue minus a *l*etter.

Find it on the lake bed! Goodbye!

HINT 1:

> Use synonyms and culture on the first line to get something to use on the second line.

HINT 2:

> Why is only *one* letter italicized?

Comment: Why is nobody answering this?

Comment: I have tried it but I think a hint is needed

Comment: What kind of hint?

Comment: I can fix the intentional misspelling on the first line

Comment: Everybody knows what to use on the second line, I think the rest of the puzzle is where they're stuck :)

Comment: Yea, but clever wordplay on ROT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> Silt

Follwing the instrutions in line 1:

> spoil = ROT
>  unlucky number = 13
>  ROT13 gives "sorry, I'm new so tihs will be spuer ez"

Using the regex:

> The regex matches the starting letter of the text, any capital, and any character which is NOT a w preceding an i
>  [image]

This is:

> missing a *l*etter - the l in italics tells us we need to add an l

The answer therefore:

> Is something that can be found on the lakebed, which is silt.

And yes:

> I have no idea what the 3>4 and 4>3 bit is for.

Comment: You did it! Congrats!

Comment: It means rot13(Gur guveq yrggre tbrf gb gur sbhegu cbfvgvba naq gur sbhegu yrggre gb gur guveq cbfvgvba.)

Comment: I got this answer on my first time looking through but, like you, I was confused on the 3 > 4 and 4 > 3 so I figured I must have missed something and refrained from posting anything.

Comment: Think of them as arrowheads :)

Comment: Was it "spuer ez"?